# nodejs reverse log number in rotation

Tags: node.js, logging

I see logs are rotated with the highest number as the latest log -

log15.log - latest
log14.log
log13.log

How can i switch the order so that log.log will be the latest?

```
var ProxyLogger = function (level,logsPath) {
    console.log("using log level: " + level);
    this.level = level;
    this.logger = new (winston.Logger)({
        transports: [

            new (winston.transports.File)({'maxsize': 128 * 1024, 'maxFiles': 10,
                'timestamp': function() { var d = new Date();
                    return d.getDate() +"-" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "-" + d.getFullYear() +" " + d.getHours() +":" + d.getMinutes() +":" +  d.getSeconds() + " " + d.getMilliseconds();}
                , filename: logsPath + '/proxy.log', level: level, 'json': false}),



            new (winston.transports.Console)({level: level, 'timestamp': function() { var d = new Date();
                return d.getDate() +"-" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "-" + d.getFullYear() +" " + d.getHours() +":" + d.getMinutes() +":" +  d.getSeconds() + " " + d.getMilliseconds();
            }})
        ]
    });
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show how these logs are generated?

Comment: I added the information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear from your question what log15.log etc are, but I can give an answer for two different scenarios.

If log#.log are just printed outputs, you can push them to an array, then on completion of your task, iterate the array backward and log each iteration, like so:

```
var logs = []

function(logmessage){ //some log generating loop
    logs.push(logmessage)
}

for(var i = log.length-1; i>0; i--){
    console.log(logs[i])
}
```

Or if log#.log are files, you can manually set their names on each iteration using:

`winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'log#.log', level: 'level' });`

Hope that helps!

Comment: I used "log.log" as an example, the actual log name is proxy.log as you can see in the code i've pasted. I need proxy.log to always be the latest and proxy1.log to be the previous one and so on.